# Homonyms/homophones and proper nouns

Tags: homophones, homonyms

I introduced my 6-year-old to the concept of "homonyms" (though I've probably got it conflated with homophones or vice-versa). Since then he's been trying to find homonyms.

He asked me just now: "Can names be homonyms? Like 'Cole' and 'coal'?"

My hypothesis is that the answer is probably "yes", but can someone answer me definitively: can nouns & same-sounding proper nouns be considered homonyms (as in the above example)?

Comment: Yes. Certainly they're homophones. (_phone_ means 'sound', so homophones have the same sound, regardless of spelling, like _bear (n), bare (adj),_ and _bear (v)_). _Nym_ means 'word', so whether it's sposta be spelling or sound is not clear. Notice that the sound came before the spelling, and keeps changing, while the spelling got frozen 500 years ago when they were speaking a different language in England (and nobody was speaking it anywhere else).

Comment: If you and your son speak American English, [this may be useful](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf) for discussing sounds.

Comment: The homonym etc terms are really only useful for explaining what might otherwise be confusing. They're usually just describing coincidences, rather like 'orchestra' and 'carthorse' being labelled anagrams. And sadly, there isn't universal agreement on the precise definition of [homonym](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homonym).

Comment: Not until there is universal agreement on the precise definition of _word_. Matthews suggests that there are three quite distinct common meanings for _word_ in English. [Diagram here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler: Impressive diagram, John. Thanks! Don

Comment: Just be careful. I always thought Don and Dawn were homophones, but it seems they are not in other parts of the U.S. Do they sound alike or different where the rest of you are?

Comment: @JohnLawler: Nobody will be able to provide a better answer than your comments, so this question is bound to remain stuck in the Unanswered list.  Could you please put your comments in an answer?

Comment: There they are, and if you understand them, the question's been answered. The question of whether it's been Officially Answered, like the status of The Unanswered List, is just bureaucracy. Nobody's payin me to be a bureaucrat any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proper nouns can be homonyms**, just like any other words.

But what is a homonym? According to Merriam-Webster, the primary meaning of [homonym](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homonyms?show=0&t=1402877756) is *a word that is spelled and pronounced like another word but is different in meaning*; the term can also refer to the related concepts of *homophones* (words that sound the same but differ in meaning or spelling) or *homographs* (words that are spelled the same but differ in pronunciation or meaning).

---

Clearly, this definition of *homonym* can be applied to proper nouns. Because [proper nouns](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proper%20noun) (including personal names like *Cole* and place names like *London*) are *still real words*, they may also be homonyms. For instance, [this article](http://esl.about.com/od/engilshvocabulary/a/hom_f_l.htm) lists *Greece* and *grease* as homonyms, even though *Greece* is most certainly a proper noun. (NB: the definition of *homonym* does not require a specific part of speech, but merely requires *a word*.)